# Auto backup photos to network drive

Tags: windows-8, backup, nas, shell-script, scheduled-tasks

My wife's ultrabook is getting full of pictures.  I have a NAS that all our pictures are on.  What I want to do is store EVERY picture on the NAS (easy) but keep all the photos from the last 12 months on the ultrabook.  Again I can do this once. But I want to run a script that does 2 things:

1. Automatically moves new pictures placed on the NAS to her ultrabook.
2. Remove any pictures on the ultrabook that are older than 12 months (the backups remain on the NAS).

It would be great if #1 copied in both directions but I can live with only one way.  If anyone could give me an idea that would be great.  I tried synctoy by ms but it will copy everything.

Thanks. We run windows 8, the NAS is synology.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Syncovery](http://www.syncovery.com/). It does that, and a lot more.

You can easily specify source & destinations, and set specific file masks and filters. In your particular case you'd say `File age less than 365 days` under `Masks & Filters`, and configure your workflow in any way you want.

I've been using Syncovery for a couple of years now (before it was called *Super Flexible File Synchronizer*) to synchronize files between my Synology NAS and my notebook, and to do a bunch of other stuff. The number of configuration option for each job is a bit overwhelming at first, but you start to appreciate the flexibility with time.

It's a commercial software, and they offer basically two versions: the Standard edition ($34.99) and the Professional version ($59.99). I have the Professional one, as I needed the realtime sync (to instantly copy modified files from a specific directory to a Dropbox folder), and also wanted to run it as a service, so I don't have to worry seeing its UI every time.

You can download a trial, and see if it works for you. I tried SyncToy and a few others, and Syncovery was by far the most advanced.

*(disclaimer: I have no association with the company, other than being a happy customer)*

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The computer in question broke down and I got to it recently.  I do not see any option of date modified on Syncovery.  It looks like an elaborate Synctoy.  This did not solve my problem but +1 for the help

Comment: @davefromcamp: which version are you using? Syncovery 6.x (latest is 6.42) has Masks & Filters, tab "File Age and Size", where you can specific a specific range, like all files modified in the last 365 days.

I'm using this to move files back-and-forth between my desktops/notebooks and Synology and Drobo NAS. The only complain I have is that [Last Modified Date is not retained when using webdev](http://www.syncovery.com/documentation/faq/modification-dates-of-files-are-not-retained-what-can-be-done/) or Amazon S3/Glacier, but works fine on Synology or any other smbfs.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a batch script a while back to do something similar with robocopy (inbuilt functionality to Windows) and ran it as a scheduled task under both Win7 and Win8 RT.

There's a pretty good guide over on the sevenforums [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/187346-robocopy-create-backup-script.html) that discusses the process in more detail. (NB: robocopy allows //server/share as a destination)

> There are many paid and free software solutions available to backup
>   critical data and files on a computer system. Many users, however, are
>   unaware of an inbuilt Windows 7 command called ROBOCOPY (Robust File
>   Copy) that allows users to create simple or highly advanced backup
>   strategies.
>
> In its simplist form, ROBOCOPY can be likened to an extension of XCOPY
>   on steroids. Some of the more important features that make ROBOCOPY an
>   attractive backup alternative are: 
>   (1) multi-threaded copying; 
>   (2) mirroring or synchronisation mode between the destination and source;
>   (3) automatic retry and copy resumption

To see the full range of options available, just type `robocopy /?` at a cmd prompt.