# Music Folder automated duplication to an external HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, music

I currently have 1TB approx. of music into a separate internal HDD. I need those files to be automatically copied into an external HDD and also update the files when i make some changes into the source music folder (internal drive). The files on the external drive must be usable (no .bak files etc), because I occasionally want to detach that drive and take the music with me on vacation or something. Is this possible with a software or something?

I prefer real time updates, but fixed interval updates are also ok for me.

I'm using win7.

Comment: Do you need realtime updates (copy process starts immediately after something changed on your internal source HDD) or are fixed interval updates enough? (e.g. every saturday 12 PM or every hour)

Comment: Thanks for your question, I edited the first first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an answer to a similar question here
[Auto backup photos to network drive](https://superuser.com/questions/598041/auto-backup-photos-to-network-drive/600663#600663)

basically use robocopy and task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Since you prefer real-time synchronization, I suggest you [DSynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) (scroll down).

- small & portable
- dead simple to use → one screenshot explains everything

[image]

[image]